# IValidatableObject only firing on SaveChanges, not IsValid

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I've got the following implementation of IValidatableObject:

```
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    if (EndDate.HasValue && EndDate < StartDate)
        yield return new ValidationResult("End date cannot be before start date", new[] { "EndDate" });
}
```

In my controller, I have:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return BadRequest(ModelState);
}
//...
DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

If I put a breakpoint on the Validate & the SaveChanges, I get to the SaveChanges first, i.e. the Validate function is not running on the IsValid line.

I believe this is not the correct behaviour. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling [`TryValidateModel()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.tryvalidatemodel(v=vs.118).aspx).  `.IsValid` does not fire validation, and that is working as intended.

The validation will fire on Model binding (if you are binding that object) and also on calls to [`TryValidateModel()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.tryvalidatemodel(v=vs.118).aspx), [`ValidateModel()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.mvc.controller.validatemodel(v=vs.118).aspx), [`TryUpdateModel()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.mvc.controller.tryupdatemodel(v=vs.118).aspx), and [`UpdateModel()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.mvc.controller.updatemodel(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, this helped me find the issue, which I didn't include in the snippet. I am using a DTO and put the validation on the database model, not the DTO model, so it wasn't firing when it was binding. This leads me to another question which I'll have to post...

Comment: @Sean, great, glad it helped.